# render text inside speech bubble Unity 2D

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

[image: Speech Bubble]

Hi, I am using Unity 2D for creating a dialogue between two people. AS you can see, I render a speech bubble sprite when a character met with someone. Then I want to have the text ("Hi how are you?") From an external resource and who it inside it. Can anyone help me with making this done? I am clueless and I tried it with text meshes but it didnt work. Thank You very much! (I am using  Javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rendering the text inside the speech bubble, you might want to consider using the so-called "new UI" that was introduced in Unity 4.6 and Unity 5. Not to be mistaken with the legacy UI system.

Documentation is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html), there are many tutorials out there (I'd post links but I don't have enough StackOverflow reputation for that).

Specifically, you'll need a object in scene having a Canvas component on it (menu `GameObject -> UI -> Canvas`), with `Render Mode` (inspector property of Canvas component) set to `World Space`.

You can then add an `Image` child object via menu `GameObject -> UI -> Image`. This will hold the image of the bubble.

Lastly, add child object to the `Image` object via menu `GameObject -> UI -> Text`. This will hold the "Hi how are you" text, you can set it via some custom script of yours once you grab it from the external file.

To show/hide the bubble with text, just deactivate the whole object via `gameObject.setActive(false)` (which will also deactivate the Text child). I have one control script which holds references to all UI objects (in this case the `Image` and the `Text`) and manipulates them as needed (activates/deactivates, sets the Text, changes the Image etc).

Admittedly, the new UI requires a bit of learning to grasp and you'll have to play around with various parameters to achieve the best effect, but it can do what you ask for.

Comment: Now that is exactly the problem. I am stuck with Unity 4.5 with legacy code. I canot work with new GUI system and thank you very much for taking time to post such a long post.

gameObject.setActive(false) was done before but then the gameObject cant be called by .Find() method. However, I seems to have find a simple method using message parsing.